# Is it possible to create a Generic API GET operation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Recently I created a service which has some logic for a GET endpoint in my API (returning all values of some database table).

The reason for creating a service for this is the fact that I want to modify GET logic at one point instead of having to change it on all my endpoints in the future.

I created a test service which works, but because I have over 50 tables (DTO classes) I want to make the service more generic.

I now have implemented the following, which is just an example of one GET operation with one DTO class :

```
public interface IOMSService
{
    IEnumerable<CommodityViewModel> GetAll(); // Can I use <T> for this? - now I need to make interface properties for every OMS class (50+)
}

public class OMSService : IOMSService
{
    private MyDBContext _context;
    private IMapper _mapper;

    public OMSService(MyDBContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public IEnumerable<CommodityViewModel> GetAll() // How to make this more generic?
    {
        var result = this._context.Commodity
                     .Include(i => i.OmsCommodityMaterial);

        var CommodityVM = _mapper.Map<IList<CommodityViewModel>>(result);

        return CommodityVM;

    }
}
```

The above example works, however, this would mean I need to implement over 50 interface properties and 50 `GetAll` implementations for every DTO class (and thus not an improvement as opposed to changing it in the endpoints itself).

Is there a way to make this more generic? 
I think the DTO part of the `IEnumerable` in the interface and `GetAll` function should be of a Generic type (so that I can just supply the right ViewModel / DTO at the endpoint itself).

I already came up with something like this:

```
public interface IOMSService<T, U>
        where T : IEnumerable<U>
{
    T GetAll { get; }
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Good question, I'd like to see an answer for this one. +1 from me on the question.

Comment: `Is there a way to make this more generic?`. Short Answer: Yes

Comment: That's what Entity Framework and LINQ-to-Entities already do.

Comment: BTW this code would load the entire `Commodity` table in memory in order to map it to `CommodityViewModel` without any filtering.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well it is called `GetAll` :)

Comment: @DavidG or "CommonOrmMistakeNum1_Blocking". I doubt that's what the OP wants

Comment: @Nicolas if you want to make your code more generic, *don't* use interfaces. Pass lambdas around as parameters, the same way LINQ does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using generics and the `Set<T>()` method of `DbContext`, you can do something like this:

```
//Note we need to make the entity and the model it maps to generic
public IEnumerable<TModel> GetAll<TEntity, TModel>(
    params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
    where TEntity : class
{
    var result = _context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();

    if(includes != null)
    {
        foreach (var include in includes)
        {
            result = result.Include(include);
        }
    }

    return _mapper.Map<IList<TModel>>(result);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var allTheThings = GetAll<Commodity, CommodityViewModel>(i => i.OmsCommodityMaterial);
```

However, to return *all* your rows is almost certainly a bad idea, so why not add in a filter while we are here:

```
public IEnumerable<TModel> Get<TEntity, TModel>(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, 
    params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes) 
    where TEntity : class
{
    var result = _context.Set<TEntity>()
        .Where(predicate);

    if(includes != null)
    {
        foreach (var include in includes)
        {
            result = result.Include(include);
        }
    }

    return _mapper.Map<IList<TModel>>(result);
}
```

Now we call it like this:

```
var someOfTheThings = Get<Commodity, CommodityViewModel>(
    x => x.SomeProperty == 42,
    i => i.OmsCommodityMaterial);
```

If you want to extract an interface from this method, I'd probably make the interface generic:

```
public interface IOMSService<TEntity>
{
    IEnumerable<TModel> Get<TModel>(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, 
        params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes) 
}
```

And then a base class:

```
public abstract class BaseOMSService<TEntity> : IOMSService<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    private MyDBContext _context;
    private IMapper _mapper;

    public BaseOMSService(MyDBContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TModel> Get<TModel>(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, 
            params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes) 
    {
        var result = _context.Set<TEntity>()
            .Where(predicate);

        if(includes != null)
        {
            foreach (var include in includes)
            {
                result = result.Include(include);
            }
        }

        return _mapper.Map<IList<TModel>>(result);
    }
}
```

And now you can make specific derived classes:

```
public class CheeseOMSService : BaseOMSService<Cheese>
{
    // snip
}

public class ZombieOMSService : BaseOMSService<Zombie>
{
    // snip
}
```

Comment: Looks great and will test it in addition to some of my own functionality (which was not posted in the main post). Just two notes, the `var result = this.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();` part is supposed to be `var result = this._context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();` ow am I wrong? And your given example does not use the interface? I tried to implement it as an interface but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Yes, the context was slightly wrong, I've corrected that. Also added an example of how you would use this as an interface.

Comment: Your my hero, great answer, and thank you for the example(s)!